# SQL to Access Linked Table Field names 66characters including square brackets

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, truncated, linked-tables, field-names

Ive migrated from Access to SQL Server 2012 but when I link my table back into the Access db I have some field names that are 64characters long, which becuase they have spaces and other special characters in them encloses them in square brackets e.g. [this field]. However the square brackets are included in the character count when creating the linked table into Access it truncates the last 2 characters off the field name e.g. [this fie].

Anyone got a way around this to ensure all 64 characters are shown in the table?

tia

M

Comment: No MS-Access has annoying limitation on objects name lengths. There is a chart with all these limitations in the documentation

Comment: Another reason to not use spaces and special characters in naming convention. Underscore is only Exception.

Comment: Apparently SQLServer has limits as well, just bigger. 128 characters for object names except for temp tables with limit of 116.

Comment: How are you linking the tables? If you use the VBA [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.DoCmd.TransferDatabase) or DAO [Database.CreateTableDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createtabledef-method-dao) method you won't be able to circumvent the 64 character limitation but you can you specify the local table name.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your feedback. What is annoying is that the users currently import spreadsheets that contain field names of 64 characters including the horrid characters ":;'#" etc and they import perfectly well from the spreadsheet into the access database, but when i do the same thing from SQL I get error after error. Very very frustrating, there are potentiall over 1000 changes i will have to do manually if I cant find a work around.

Comment: To iterate, it isnt the table name im having issues with, it is the field names.